# Incidence matrix of a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Are there any special properties for the incidence matrix when a graph is planar?

Comment: The four-color theorem can be expressed as putting the incidence matrix in a $4 \times 6$ block form, where each block is a permutation matrix or zero, I guess.

Comment: Thanks! But I am more curious about the spectral properties of the incidence matrix, like the structure of the kernel space of the matrix.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in the *Colin de Verdière graph invariant* of the graph. A *Colin de Verdière matrix* is a matrix related to the adjacency and Laplace matrix of the graph (which can be recovered from the incidence matrix), and the largest possible kerner of such a matrix (which is exactly the mention graph invariant) is $\le 3$ if and only if the graph is planar.

Comment: A couple of references are https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-spectral-radius-of-a-planar-graph-Cao-Vince/25082629db601073443980da4096ec16351da296 and http://stanford.edu/~jugander/notes/CS6822_Lecture8_SpielmanTeng.pdf.